# Entity Framework: Exclude audit properties from migration changes

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I have a solution with a Data Access layer driven by Entity Framework. All works fine and have about 57 entities. Each entity inherit from an EntityBase class which contains audit fields which are only updated if there are changes to the records. However, for some reason when I perform my migration, my records seem to have been modified and this updates the entity audit fields and makes my migration process each time take 24minutes to run. The one table seeds data and has 115000 rows which get run 'Update' each time.

EntityBase:

```
public abstract class EntityBase
    {
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(200)]
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(200)]
        public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateUpdated { get; set; }
        [Timestamp]
        public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }

    }
```

How audit fields are updated in the Context class:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
        {
            try
            {
                SetAudit();

                return base.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
            {
                var sb = new StringBuilder();

                foreach (var failure in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    sb.AppendFormat("{0} failed validation\n", failure.Entry.Entity.GetType());
                    foreach (var error in failure.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        sb.AppendFormat("- {0} : {1}", error.PropertyName, error.ErrorMessage);
                        sb.AppendLine();
                    }
                }

                throw new DbEntityValidationException("Entity Validation Failed - errors follow:\n" + sb, ex); // Add the original exception as the innerException
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

private void SetAudit()
        {
            var addedAuditedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries<EntityBase>().Where(p => p.State == EntityState.Added)
                .Select(p => p.Entity);
            var modifiedAuditedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries<EntityBase>().Where(p => p.State == EntityState.Modified)
                .Select(p => p.Entity);
            var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
            foreach (var added in addedAuditedEntities)
            {
                added.DateCreated = now;
                added.CreatedBy = OwinContextHelper.CurrentApplicationUser;
                added.DateUpdated = now;
                added.UpdatedBy = OwinContextHelper.CurrentApplicationUser;
            }

            foreach (var modified in modifiedAuditedEntities)
            {
                if (modified.DateCreated == DateTime.MinValue)
                    modified.DateCreated = now;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(modified.CreatedBy))
                    modified.CreatedBy = OwinContextHelper.CurrentApplicationUser;
                modified.DateUpdated = now;
                modified.UpdatedBy = OwinContextHelper.CurrentApplicationUser;
            }
        }
```

How do I exclude my audit fields from migration as I take it, it's the 'RowVersion' that could be changing?

Comment: I guess the answer is in the seeding code.

Comment: I ended up commenting out the seed data. Lol